# TemplateRoles Adding, not replacing signer

Tags: docusignapi

[Left Column 'Get' recipients, Right Col 'Post' envelopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh5sP.png)

The problem is Instead of Replacing the Client as I expected based on docs.

It Added a second signer to the process. My template was set up for two roles Advisor and Client. I excpected the client to ONLY be the one I passed via the api. Instead it sent 3 emails total. One to Template Client, One to Template Advisor and one to Api Passed Client.

Unless I misunderstand the api function, It should not have sent an email to 
original template Client.

Comment: In your template, you already have filled name and email of the client. If you will remove it from template and send the envelope, then it will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, it usually means that the values you specified for the recipient in your "Create Envelope" API call did not ***exactly match*** the values that the template specified for the recipient role (i.e., **roleName**, etc.).

To resolve this issue, I'd suggest that you issue a "Get Recipients" call for your template (`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients`) to identify the exact values that the template defines for the "Client" recipient role, and then ensure that your "Create Envelope" API request specifies the ***same exact values*** (including case) for the recipient that you want to occupy the "Client" role. If you try this and still can't figure it out, then please update your question with your "Create Envelope" request and the results of the "Get Recipients" request, and someone here on SO will likely be able to spot your issue.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I did my best to edit my question to provide the information you requested. Let me know if you need anything more or if I should submit it differently.

Answer (score 0):

The template `b521bece-6440-430a-9762-bf8d4543edc5` already has the recipient email/name filled.

Since recipients details are already filled, in the template, you will not be able to substitute the values during envelope creation.

You can modify the template and leave the name and email fields empty.

Then [Create the envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) with just a single recipient. The notifications will only be sent to the single recipient.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes


{
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "b521bece-6440-430a-9762-bf8d4543edc5",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "mike@acme.com",
      "name": "Mike TestName",
      "roleName": "Client"
    }
  ]
}
```